# Ruby System command isn't taking `echo -n`

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm trying to use the `system` command to output text to a file. I'm using `echo -n` and passing `-n` so it doesn't automatically create a newline in the file. Here's the command I'm using:
`system("echo -n \"text for the file\" >> path/to/file.txt")`

When I check the text file, the output that I get is:
`-n text for file`

If I run that same exact command in my terminal, I don't get the `-n`

Why is it not accepting the `-n` as an argument?

Comment: Why are you shelling out write text to a file in the first place? Just open the file in Ruby and write to it.

Comment: Using `system` for this is not only heavy-handed and clumsy, it can cause serious problems if your filenames are specified by the user and you don't make an effort to escape them and protect yourself against shell injection. `system` should be a last-resort tool.

Comment: Also, as @chepner says: `File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'a') { |f| f.write("text" }` and done, all this can be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo -n` is not portable. Use `printf` instead to print the string.

```
system("printf 'text of the file' >> path/to/file.txt")
```

Specifically, the POSIX specification allows a conforming implementation of `echo` to support a `-n` option, but does not require it or define what it should do. Your `system` call is using a shell (probably `dash`) that does not implement `-n` and treats it as a regular argument to write to standard output.

Comment: Yes. +1. Ruby uses `/bin/sh` on Unix for `system` and `\`` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Alongside, chepner's useful answer, since the `system()` call calling the native implementation of `echo` which does not implement the `-n` functionality, you could call the `FreeBSD` or a `GNU` based installation of `echo` installed explicitly as below,

In `Mac OS` the `FreeBSD` version of `echo` is installed as `/bin/echo` which you can use as

```
system("/bin/echo -n \"text for the file\" >> path/to/file.txt")
```

As a side-note, you could first see if `echo` is installed by doing `which echo` before running this.